# How to change the color of chart based on sub level values in a Drill down report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

The report contains 3 drill-downs - Parent level(Year), child-level1(Submodel), child-level2(Engine), and details(System). The parent level has a bar chart inserted in the header of an adjacent column to display the count of Submodels. On drilling down to child-level1 a bar chart is displayed showing counts of systems.
I would like to dynamically change the color of the bar chart at parent level depending on the counts of systems in child-level1. If all the submodels have the same system count then "Green", if not "Red".
In the screenshot attached the bar beside 2016 must be green and the one beside 2017 must be red. Please let me know if it is feasible and how.[image]

Comment: Are those charts, spark lines or gauges? They don't really look like charts, unless you really stripped the chart down.  If they're charts, I would suggest replacing them with gauges, since they're easier to manage and give you some flexibility that a chart lacks.  With a gauge, it's very simple to conditionally set the color of the bar you're using just by accessing the value you're using in the System column.

Comment: My bad it is a Data Bar with Count of systems in values. How can it be conditionally set up?

Comment: You can set up the conditional color in the Series Properties screen (under "Fill") for the Data Bar.

Comment: I did write a condition as follows but that doesn't seem to work =IIF(MIN(Countdistinct(system))=MAX(Countdistinct(system)),"Green","Red"). The intention is to identify if the systems count of all underlying submodels is the same or not.

Comment: You need to add a scope parameter to the CountDistinct, MIN and MAX that matches the group name for "Sub Model" (case sensitive).  With the way you have it written, you're checking the entire dataset.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked just as expected! It works great when I apply it as an expression for fill in adjust blank row but when attempting to add expression for data bar chart palette it throws an error - THe palette expression specifies a scope that is nor valid for a nested aggregate.

Comment: Data bar under Submodel column has an expression =CountDistinct(Fields!sub_model.Value) and I am trying to add above mentioned IIF condition for color change and it wouldn't accept that.